Crash in CollectionView when Bluetooth device is connected
the collectionview works fine til some bluetooth device is connected. Than it crashes and only some long message comes in the Debugger view.
*** Assertion failure in -[MyApp.DataCollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:], UICollectionView.m:3964

I use some DecorationView and an own Layout but it creates there. When Bluetooth tastature is disconnected everything is fine. My best guess is that some recognizer is connecting the collectionview and doing weired stuff.
